# How to use where clause in Parse Installation Class?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I created a Cloud Code function to send Push Notifications to a group of users. Everything works well if I comment out the where clause line. I tried everything, but with no success. Even if I put in a hardcoded objectId, it doesn't work. The "groups" column is an Array of strings.

```
var pushQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
pushQuery.equalTo("groups", "lpyG0aHTBZ");
Parse.Push.send({
    where: pushQuery,
    data: {
        alert: "xxxxx"
    }
});
```

Comment: It looks fine.  As a test, see what happens when you run the query.  Instead of parse.push, try pushQuery.find(), and log the results.

Comment: If i do find(), it works well. The results i expect come correctly. Dam :(

Comment: You get the installation back that you expect?  And can you confirm that installation is associated with a device that can and has authorized the receipt of pushes, and that you've observed that device not getting the push, even after a short wait?  If so, I'm stumped.

Comment: Yes. Like i said, if i comment the equalTo line, i receive the push. Looks like a parse problem.

Comment: I have tryed also to change the equalTo to something like: pushQuery.equalTo("deviceToken", "xxxx") and hardcoded my token and still no push.

Comment: Right, but you know the query works as written because you ran it.  Lets investigate the return.  Can you add a success and error function to the push and log what's passed to both?

Comment: I did it. What u want me to return in success? i returned the result of the find. It returned an array of 2 Installations (the ones i expect). Its not giving error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99262/discussion-between-danh-and-rodrigo-manguinho).

Comment: @danh. It was a bug at Parse. I created a new project and just worked with the same code. Weird... Anyway, hope this can help someone in the future.